# MySQL Select Values from Jan 1 to yesterday

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I have three different pieces of code.  One selects all values from yesterday (12am to 11:59pm).  The next selects all values from the start of the current month (in this case 12am 9/1 to 11:59pm 9/24).  The third is "supposed" to select all values from the start of the year (12am 1/1 to 11:59pm 9/24).  However, I am doing something wrong because it is taking all values from the beginning of time (mid 2016).  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Yesterday:

```
select LogDateTime, UVindex 
from monthly_new 
where LogDateTime between current_date - interval 1 day and current_date;
```

This month:

```
select LogDateTime, UVindex 
from monthly_new 
where LogDateTime between current_date - dayofmonth(current_date) + 1 and current_date;
```

This year (not working):

```
select LogDateTime, UVindex 
from monthly_new 
where LogDateTime between current_date - dayofyear(current_date) + 1 and current_date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `date_format()` for this; it makes it easy to truncate to month or year, and takes advantage of MySQL flexibility to treat strings as dates.

To filter from the beginning of the year until today:

```
 LogDateTime between date_format(current_date, '%Y-01-01') and current_date
```

From the beginning of the month:

```
 LogDateTime between date_format(current_date, '%Y-%m-01') and current_date
```

Comment: Ah I see.  The month queries work, so I'll probably leave them be, but this year one is exactly what I needed.  Thanks!